# Copy contents of a repo to another repo inside a folder, retaining history, branches, tags

Tags: git

I want to copy the contents of a git repository to another repository inside a folder.

SourceRepo/ 
     -A
     -B

TargetRepo
     -C
     -D
     folder/

i want to move (A,B) inside folder/ with branch and commit history.

Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you merge two Git repositories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425892/how-do-you-merge-two-git-repositories)

Answer (score 0):

The git subtree command does exactly what you want. Execute the following command on TargetRepo in the branch you want to add it to:

```
git subtree add --prefix=folder <git-url-of-SourceRepo> master
```

This will add SourceRepo's master branch inside folder in your TargetRepo.